# page freeze after alert from loaded element with jquery

Tags: jquery, freeze

i have jquery script to load select element to div element on the current page
and i have event to alert if some element value has been select

the problem is, if selected option doesn't have alert, everything ok, but if selected option has alert, then the page like freeze. I can't input any data to all available input field or select on that page

here's the code

```
    //select company event
$('#company_id').change( function()
{
    //remove or reset all handler event
    $('#div_casetype').off();

    $(this).find(":selected").each(function () 
    {
        $('#tr_casetype').hide();
        $('#div_casetype').html('');

        if( parseInt($(this).val()) > 0 
        && $(this).val() != '' 
        )
        {
            $('#tr_casetype').show();

            $('#div_casetype').load('get_casetype.php?company_id='+ $(this).val() +'&z='+ Math.random() )
            .on('change', '#casetype_id', function()
            {
                $(this).find(':selected').each( function() 
                {
                    if( parseInt($(this).val()) == 3 )
                    {
                        alert('TES WARNING 3');
                    }

                    if( parseInt($(this).val()) == 4 )
                    {
                        alert('TES WARNING 4');
                    }

                    if( parseInt($(this).val()) == 6 )
                    {
                        alert('TES WARNING 6');
                    }

                    $('#q_sn').focus();
                });

            }); 
        }

    });
});
```

if i select value 1, everything ok, but if i select value 3 that have warning, after alert come out, the page become freeze

please help me, thank you

update, this html form

```
<tr valign="top">
  <td width="80">Company</td>
  <td width="6">:</td>
  <td width="592">
  <select id="company_id" name="company_id">
  <option value=""></option>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_company";

$sql_company = mysql_query($query);

while( $rw_company = mysql_fetch_array( $sql_company ) )
{
echo '<option value="'. $rw_company['company_id'] .'" >'. $rw_company['company_name'] .'</option>';
}
?>
  </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_casetype" style="display:none;" valign="top">
  <td>Case type</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><div id="div_casetype"></div></td>
</tr>
```

this get_casetype.php file

```
<select id="casetype_id" name="casetype_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_casetype
WHERE 1 
AND company_id='". addslashes($company_id) ."'
";

$sql_casetype = mysql_query($query);

while( $rw_casetype = mysql_fetch_array($sql_casetype) )
{
    echo '<option value="'. $rw_casetype['casetype_id'] .'" >'. $rw_casetype['casetype_name'] .'</option>';
}
?>

</select>
```

thank you

Comment: Can you please share the markup?

Comment: what you mean with markup? sorry i'm newbie here

Comment: this is full source page http://pastebin.com/eiLC1Z7U